# How to restore bash history function in macOS Sierra

Tags: terminal, bash, history

I installed Sierra OS on my iMac without any troubles. But, when I open Terminal, I can't scroll through the bash history when pressing the up arrow.

Comment: I am assuming you mean, "scroll through the bash history when pressing the up arrow."  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`. The file contains comments that explain how to disable bash_sessions:

```
# The save/restore mechanism is disabled if the following file exists:
#
# ~/.bash_sessions_disable
```

or just disable their shell history mechanism

```
# You may disable this behavior and share a single history by setting
# SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 0. There are some common user customizations
# that arrange to share new commands among running shells by
# manipulating the history at each prompt, and they typically include
# 'shopt -s histappend'; therefore, if the histappend shell option is
# enabled, per-session history is disabled by default. You may
# explicitly enable it by setting SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps also restore the (hidden) *.bash_history*  file from the TimeMachine backup
Found in the HomeFolder.